# Need to join RHEL 8.5 to AD using SSSD

Tags: linux, domain, sssd

How do i join my RHEL 8.5 server to AD using sssd?
Is there a standard working process for AD joining.
I have used adcli , realm join but there is always instability.

Also is there a standard way to create `/etc/krb5.keytab` and `/etc/krb5.conf` as well.

mydomain is say example-inc.local

Also my log file is filled with below error

```
Mar 27 15:39:59 server-e01 ldap_child[356119]: Failed to initialize credentials using keytab [MEMORY:/etc/krb5.keytab]: Preauthentication failed. Unable to create GSSAPI-encrypted LDAP connection.
```

Comment: Please show the `adcli` and `realm` commands you're using. Also include the configuration file `sssd.conf` particularly if you've made changes

Answer (score 4):

RedHat offer very [detailed document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/integrating_rhel_systems_directly_with_windows_active_directory/connecting-rhel-systems-directly-to-ad-using-sssd_integrating-rhel-systems-directly-with-active-directory) how to join RH to AD. Do you follow all the steps:

- Install the following packages:

  `# yum install samba-common-tools realmd oddjob oddjob-mkhomedir sssd adcli krb5-workstation`
- To display information for a specific domain, run realm discover and add the name of the domain you want to discover:

  `# realm discover ad.example.com`
- Configure the local RHEL system with the realm join command. The realmd suite edits all required configuration files automatically. For example, for a domain named ad.example.com:

  `# realm join ad.example.com`

Verification steps

- Display an AD user details, such as the administrator user:

  `# getent passwd administrator@ad.example.com`

Comment: quoting from the Low Quality Review queue, "it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes." Please make this answer self-contained (or wait until the OP's problem becomes clearer). Thank you!